# how to avoid row duplicate in crystal report?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

crystal report have duplicated rows when i use suppress  if duplicate its hide value only not full row 
as shown in picture 
As Example

```
ACT Status
987 Blank
987 received
987
252 Blank
252 received
475 Blank
522 Received
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Select Distinct Records` so that only distinct records are displayed.

write a condition in supress of the section not on the column.

```
if ACT=next(ACT)
then true
else false
```